# TeamCity doesn't send a notification if a build triggered against any branch but default

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0, buildconfiguration

I am subscribed to different types of notifications, such as Build Starts and Build Fails events. My build configuration has a single VCS attached and a VCS trigger that kicks off a build on each commit to any branch.

The problem is that when the build starts against the default branch I do get both an email and TeamCity Tray Notifier message, but if a build gets triggered against any non-default branch (either manually or via trigger) I don't get notified at all.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the very best idea to answer my own question but my further research has shown that there is a reported bug on this matter: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-25487
TeamCity's official states that the bug was fixed but "This feature will appear in 9.0. Hopefully by the end of this year."
So there is nothing to do about it yet unfortunately.